# How can i connect react frontend to sails js

Tags: reactjs, templates, frontend, sails.js, ejs

I have created sails app which uses `ejs` template as frontend. But now I have changed my mide , now I want `react` componet should replace `ejs` files .How can I do this ?

overall I want use `react` frontend for sails app.

Please help me ,Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [A generator to create a new ReactJS web platform powered by Sails](https://github.com/erikschlegel/sails-generate-reactjs).

Comment: This is not in maintainence, since 7 years